# C# Crystal Reports using wildcard * on non-string types in selection formula

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to do a wildcard search criteria from my application in Crystal Reports. The issue I am having is if the user does a wildcard on a non-string field such as an int I get the following error.

> Error in formula Record_Selection: A number, currency amount, boolean, date, time, date-time, or string is expected here.

The query is:

`1 = 1 AND (( {TestGroup.IsActive} IN [Yes])) AND (( {Test.IsActive} IN [Yes])) AND (( {Test.TestScreenID} LIKE 55*))`

From what I can figure out this is because {Test.TestScreenID} is an int in the database and that is why I am getting the error. If I try doing a wildcard on any string column in the database it works as expected.

How do I perform a wildcard search when the column datatype may not always be a string?

Comment: I think its better to perform the search in crystal reports rather than in query.. take whole data into reports and then convert the database field to text and perform the search

Comment: Use TOTEXT({int_field}) and then apply your formula. This converts the field to string.